# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: sql-server-2008, production-environment

I have web application which we deployed in a production .
We have separate servers for WEB and Database. The DB is SQL Server 2008 and it is hosted on a completely different server and we have our IIS installed on a different server.

On my web server, we get following error.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies

I checked the GAC on the web server and it was missing this particular DLL. This makes sense to me since it is a web server and it is not supposed to have assemblies related to SQLServer.

Our application worked great in our dev, test and staging environment as our IIS and DB were installed on same server.

How do I get past this issue on Production? I can, by installing SQL Server 2008 on the web server. But this is does not make sense to me. It is a web server - why should I install SQL Server 2008 on that machine?

Comment: SVI- You have dependencies on the SQL Types in your application, so you must have those assemblies on any box to which you install your application.  That is why you must install these SQL bits to your webserver.  The Feature Pack is provided so that you can install supporting SQL assemblies without installing the full server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=16978)

Brief Description:

Download the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack, a collection of stand-alone install packages that provide additional value for SQL Server 2008.  Specifically the CLR Data Types.

**Note: Updated feature pack link Jan 2013**

Comment: Dave, 
I am having difficulty understanding why should I be installing any components related SQL SERVER on my web server.

Comment: Dave, I see where you coming from.. Do you mean, I should install Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types DESCRIPTION:
The SQL Server System CLR Types package contains the components implementing the new geometry, geography, and hierarchyid types in SQL Server 2008. This component can be installed separately from the server to allow client applications to use these types outside of the server.

Comment: Because you want to use the SQL Server spatial types.

Comment: This proved to be the case for us using AWS with Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 to connect to SQL Server 2014 using some legacy dlls where the specific version "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack" CLR Types installs the 10.0.xx that resolves the error thrown here.

Comment: I'm getting this error on a machine where SQL Server IS already installed. Do I need to install the feature pack even though SQL Server is already installed?

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper The spatial types may not be installed by default, so it's possible you have to install them explicitly even when SQL Server is already installed.

Answer (score 16):

report viewer need this class

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll
```

Comment: I used NuGet to install `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution would be to install the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types NuGet package.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

And follow instructions from its readme.htm

Comment: additionally - once the nuget package is installed you can ensure that the dll reference property is set to 'copy local = true'

Comment: The nuget may install the newest version, however, the server may requires client to use a older version, so this is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

As @Dave Swersky Said Require Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack

But link has been changed to:

Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2008 R2:

X86 Package(SQLSysClrTypes.msi): http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188391&clcid=0x409
X64 Package (SQLSysClrTypes.msi): http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188392&clcid=0x409

Use original link will get a text file saying that package has been separate

Answer (score 1):

I was able to ignore this error by simply pressing the "Continue" button when the error appeared. It didn't appear to effect operation of the 2008 R2 server once the install finished. I'm running Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this forum post: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7e673dde-dfca-4b1a-a840-025a2ae9ee58/reportviewer-msi-is-missing-microsoftsqlservertypesdll?forum=sqlreportingservices,

the first response. You can actually download the redistributable report viewer runtime .dlls and add the to your project so that they are deployed to machines that don't have those files.

And the link to actually downloading the runtime for VS 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/EN-US/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35747

PS you can also download them via NuGet (which is what I did.) Just search for "MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME " and they should come up - easiest way so far

Answer (score -4):

For me Close the application and reopen it solve the problem